# Set default value for single instance in IBOutletCollection?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have an IBOutletCollection that loads a custom UI control instanced from my ViewController.m. Then the control is duplicated in the .xib. Only problem is that they all have the same default values. Is there a way to address individual index's in the IBOutletCollection Array and set default values?

Comment: Why are you using IBOutletCollection ? You should use IBOutlet for each component you link in nib interface file (aka. XIB).

Comment: Using IBOutletCollection because I am loading many instances of the same custom UI class. Many init settings are taken care of in the NSArray and I didn't want to have to define 12 individual controls. But I do need to define 1 or two individual params per instance.